# Custom SessionAuthentication logic not working in my Django REST Framework project

Tags: django, authentication, session, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

So, the problem is with my custom implementation of SessionAuthentication. I researched google and [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication) trying to find a way to implement a logic of authenticating Custom User by his telegram_id and personal code, which is defined this way:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    telegram_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    is_curator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    developer_result = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    design_result = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default=12345678)
    password = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'telegram_id'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.telegram_id)
```

Then I created a similar to the example in the documentation CustomAuthentication class:

```
class CustomAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        telegram_id = request.data.get('telegram_id')
        code = request.data.get('code')

        if not telegram_id or not code:
            return None

        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(telegram_id=telegram_id, code=code) # get the user
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Неверный логин или пароль') # raise exception if user does not exist

        return (user, None)
```

Created a serializer for login:

```
class CustomLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    telegram_id = serializers.CharField()
    code = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        telegram_id = validated_data['telegram_id']
        code = validated_data['code']
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(telegram_id=telegram_id, code=code)
        return user
```

API view, allowing anybody to have access to it:

```
class CustomUserLogin(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, CustomAuthentication)
    serializer_class = CustomLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CustomLoginSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        login(request, user)
        return Response("Login successful", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and defined a url path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router_v1.urls)),
    path('login/', CustomUserLogin.as_view(), name='custom_user_login'),
]
```

I did not forgot to set the following settings, protetcting other endpoints (apart of login) from accessing them without authentication:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

So. Now I make a post request (via swagger or postman - doesn't work either way) to  [`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login`](http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login/) with a telegram_id and code of a user and it responds with  "`Login Succesful"` and code 200. So it seems to be working.

```
curl -X 'POST' \  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login/' \   -H 'accept: application/json' \   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \   -H 'X-CSRFToken: qa9DH9ost3rW6cwQUTH13k8hggzMMEV01TMqrqWPs3by3BI2L6iHyXxKF3FzuikP' \   -d '{   "telegram_id": "41243",   "code": "12345678" }'
```

**BUT!**

When I'm trying to access another API endpoint, it is saying like I did not login. Here is the request (made automatically by swagger):

```
curl -X 'GET' \  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/chapters/' \   -H 'accept: application/json' \   -H 'X-CSRFToken: qa9DH9ost3rW6cwQUTH13k8hggzMMEV01TMqrqWPs3by3BI2L6iHyXxKF3FzuikP'
```

And here is the response:

403 ***Undocumented*** Error: Forbidden

```
{  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }
```

What may cause this problem? I cannot find any way to make it work properly.

I tried changing settings, tried authenticating via django admin panel and then making swagger requests (yes, it works, but custom login doesn't and it didn't bring me an idea of why it doesn't work)
Tried removing and adding back login function.